# Getting abnormal error in Page View Counter using PHP

Tags: php

I have page view counter script which `fwrite` in a .txt file and I echo it in another file where I have to display the page views. The counter updating script is:

```
$handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
if(!$handle){

    echo "could not open the file" ;

} else {

    $counter = (int ) fread($handle,20);
    fclose ($handle);
    $counter++;
    $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" );
    fwrite($handle,$counter) ;
    fclose ($handle) ;
}
```

The above code writes (`fwrite`) page views in file name `counter.txt`

And the page where I want to show page views is also a combination of HTML and PHP. The code I have added there is following which read views and displays it

```
$handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r"); 
if(!$handle){ 
    echo "could not open the file" ; 
} else { 
    $counter = ( int ) fread ($handle,20) ; 
}

echo $counter;
```

The above code shows the page views. It reads from the `counter.txt` file and displays page views.

I am getting abnormal error for this. When I am trying to access the file via `desktop` it shows wrong page view. It adds extra `1` view. for e.g. if there is only `1` page view it shows `2`

But on `android` or `ios` devices it is working fine. For `android` or `ios` devices it showing correct count. I want to know is there any problem with the code? In short above script is showing +1 (extra 1 view) every time. (only for laptops or pc's)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226820/discussion-on-question-by-andy-getting-abnormal-error-in-page-view-counter-using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    // page-count.php - to be included in other files

    class hitcounter{
        private $file;
        private static $instance=false;
        
        private function __construct($file){
            $this->file=$file;
        }
        public static function initialise( $file ){
            if( !self::$instance ) self::$instance=new self( $file );
            return self::$instance;
        }
        public function write(){
            $i=$this->read();
            $i++;
            file_put_contents($this->file,$i,LOCK_EX);
        }
        public function read(){
            return file_exists($this->file) ? (int)file_get_contents($this->file) : 0;
        }
        public function display(){
            printf('<p>Page hits: %s</p>Filename: %s',$this->read(),$this->file);
        }
    }
    
    $file=sprintf('counter-%s.txt',ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    
    $oHit=hitcounter::initialise( $file );
?>
```

The page that will update the textfile

```
<?php

    require 'page-count.php';
    # log the page view to the text file
    $oHit->write();
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Update & display hitcount</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Update & View PageView count</h1>
        <a href='view-page-count.php'>View counter</a> | <a href='javascript:location.reload(true)'>Reload</a>
        <?php
            # display the hit count
            $oHit->display();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The page that will view the results only ( view-page-count.php )

```
<?php
    require 'page-count.php';
    // do NOT log this page view - only display the count
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Display hitcount</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Previous Page</a>
        <h1>This page only VIEWS logfile - it does NOT update it.</h1>
        <?php
            $oHit->display();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated by others, doing a counter with a simple file in PHP is not a good idea. There are many hits on a webpage you are not aware of (e.g. search-engines, known and unknown spiders, normal visitors, ...). These may or may not interfere and want access to this file at the same time. This results in unclear situations which may result in weird errors. Therefore the foremost hint is to use a database which is able to lock the data during access and makes it safe to add the data.

Lets look into your code:
One of the biggest problem is, that writing your file means the OS clears the file and rewrites it. In the worst case it means a harddisc starts, positiones itself at the file, tries to open it, clears it, writes data to it and closes it afterwards. This will take many cycles - enough time to get interrupted by others who try to visit your page as well. Sure a SSD works much faster but not in terms of data-collisions.

If you cannot use a Database we need to try to "lock" your file for single-usage. Here is your updated code:

```
$handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
if(!$handle){
    echo "could not open the file" ;
} else {
   $counter = (int ) fread($handle,20);
   fclose ($handle);
   $counter++;

   $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" );
   if (flock($handle, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
       fwrite($handle, $counter) ;
       flock($handle, LOCK_UN);   // open the lock again
   }
   fclose ($handle) ;
}
```

This tries to lock your file. If it is not lockable it will not block the further execution but pass the fwrite-line. You can remove the LOCK_NB but this means your server will wait till the block is liftet and this may take a while. Blocking a webserver is not a good idea so maybe not counting a visitor is the better way.

A **third** - a bit more complex - way is to write unique files for visitors in a directory and an automatic collector (e.g. cron-job) of the votes who has a single access to your visitor-file. This way you get no collisions.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks! I will check that !